# Observable.flatMapLatest: Cancel at a deeper level?

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, bacon.js

I'm experimenting with reactive programming for the first time, using [bacon.js](/questions/tagged/bacon.js), and hit an odd interaction that's annoying me. I came up with a working version of this event chain, but the hackish extra stream manipulations makes it stand out from the rest of the code --  as you'll see.

I found FRP/Bacon.js to generate some pretty clean code, so it feels like I'm just missing some obvious operators. To the problem, shall we?

Several sources recommend using `Observable.flatMapLatest` to discard stale events. Suppose we want to complete an IO operation for each event in an input stream. In the following diagram, `i` represents the input stream events, `rN`s represent the events of each of the request streams and the `x`es mark the point in time when a request stream was cancelled. These are most likely one-event streams, so the `.` means the stream is actually closed after the event (if it wasn't cancelled before!).

```
             input stream:  i──i────────i───i─────────>   
                  request:  │  │        │   └────r4.──>   
                  request:  │  │        └───x─r3.─────>   
                  request:  │  └──r2.───x─────────────>   
                  request:  └──x─────r1.──────────────>   
                                                        + 
i.flatMapLatest(requests):  ──────r2─────────────r4───>
```

This is perfectly okay for several use cases, but pay attention to `r3`: it never gets accepted, even though it was still a valid response until `r4` arrived. In the worst case scenario, lots of requests are wasted:

```
             input stream:  i──i──i───i──i──────>   
                  request:  │  │  │   └──x─r4.──>   
                  request:  │  │  └───x─r3.─────>   
                  request:  │  └──x─r2.─────────>   
                  request:  └──x─────r1.────────>   
                                                  + 
i.flatMapLatest(requests):  ────────────────────>
```

I know we can use `throttle` and `debounce` to deal with these kinds of situation, but they're still susceptible to (bigger) timing problems. For example, a user on a spotty connection (on which requests take between 0.5s-5s+) could be the severely affected by this.

Now, even if it's not a real problem, it looks like it'd be valuable for my FRP study. If it's not clear by now, this is what I want to do:

```
             input stream:  i──i────────i───i─────────>   
                  request:  │  │        │   └────r4.──>   
                  request:  │  │        └─────r3.─x───>   
                  request:  │  └──r2.──────────x──────>   
                  request:  └──────x─r1.──────────────>   
                                                        + 
i.flatMap_What?(requests):  ──────r2──────────r3─r4───>
```

And here's my current implementation vs. the basic `flatMapLatest` one:

```
var wrong = function (interval, max_duration) {
    var last_id = 0,
        interval = interval || 1000,
        max_duration = max_duration || 5000;

    Bacon.interval(interval, 'bang').log('interval:')
        .flatMapLatest(function () {
            return Bacon.later(Math.random()*max_duration, last_id++).log(' request:');
        })
        .log('accepted: %s **********');
};

var right = function (interval, max_duration) {
    var last_id = 0,
        interval = interval || 1000,
        max_duration = max_duration || 5000;

    Bacon.interval(interval, 'bang').log('interval:')
        .flatMap(function () {
            return Bacon.later(Math.random()*max_duration, last_id++).log(' request:');
        })
        .diff(-1, function (a, b) { return b > a ? b : -1 })
        .filter(function (id) { return id !== -1 })
        .log('accepted: %s **********');    
};
```

The `wrong` function ignores successive requests as expected, while the `right` function operates on a plain `flatMap` with a `diff` and `filter`. But not only that looks very hacky, it adds the timestamp/id as a requirement for the requests, just so we can sort it later.

I guess my question is, then: What am I missing? Is there a better way to do this? How can I `takeUntil` each of the `flatMap` event streams (request) instead of the outer one (input)?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think most of the time `flatMapLatest` is doing what you want: if the input has changed, the result of the previous request is invalid. A simple example would be search field text and corresponding search results.

Comment: In your example you should use `scan` instead of diff and maintain the max id that has come through: if results come in order [r3, r1, r2], the wrong thing will go through.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses max id and scan:

```
var right = function (interval, max_duration) {
    var bang_id = 0, last_id = 0,
        interval = interval || 1000,
        max_duration = max_duration || 5000;

    Bacon.interval(interval, 'bang')
        .map(function() { return 'Bang'+(bang_id++) })
        .flatMap(function (val) {
            return Bacon.later(Math.random()*max_duration, {value: val, id: last_id++});
        })
        .scan({id: -1, value: null}, function(memo, v) {
          if(v.id <= memo.id) {
            return memo;
          }
          return v;
        })
        .changes()
        .skipDuplicates(function(a, b) { return a.id === b.id; })
        .map('.value')
        .log();    
};
```

http://jsbin.com/doreqa/3/edit?js,console